# Trying to iterate a group of elements based on a key in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having problems iterating a key value in XSLT. I have this line:

```
<xsl:key name="group" match="Orders" use="number" />
```

and after this :

```
<xsl:variable name="orderNodes">    
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', number)" />
</xsl:variable>
```

I am trying to iterate with this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$orderNodes/Orders">
  <xsl:value-of select="number" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

but I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
           :Error checking type of the expression 'FilterParentPath(variable-ref(groupNodes/result-tree), step("child", 14))'.
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `xsl:variable name="orderNodes"` but then you try to use `$group` which doesn't make sense.

As for using a variable, first consider whether you really need a copy or can't just select the input nodes with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="group" select="key('group', number)"/>`, then using e.g. `$group/number` should work with any version of XSLT and any XSLT processor without errors.

If you really need a copy as in your original code, then take notice that with an XSLT 1.0 processor you create a result tree fragment which then needs to be converted to a node-set first to be able to select nodes in it:

```
<xsl:variable name="group-rtf">    
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('group', number)" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="group" select="exsl:node-set($group-rtf)" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$group/Orders/number">...
```